# Branching process question.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have a branching process, where at each time $n$, each individual produces offspring independently with the distribution $\{p_k\}$ and then dies with probability $0 < q < 1$.

For what values of $q, p_k$, do we have extinction with probability $1$?

I'm kind of stuck because most branching processes I've done assumes that the individual dies immediately after reproducing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First, what have you tried so far. Where are you stuck? For clarity, you might want to mention how many offspring are produced at each step? Since parents can keep living, it seems that even producing 1 offspring would work. What is the significance of the subscript k?

Comment: This is what I have done so far: Suppose $X_0=1$. This individual's contribution to the next generation, say $Y_1$ has the following distribution, $P(Y_1=0)=qp_0$ and $P(Y_1=n)=qp_n + (1-q)p_{n-1}$ for $n>0$. Hence it turns out that it is a regular branching process with new $(p_n)$'s. Now computing expected value, if $\mu \le 1$ then extinction probability is 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is strongly related to the Galton-Watson process.  http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/312/Branching.pdf

For example:
If $\mu > 1$ and even with $q=1$, your process is not extinct with constant probability, by looking at the Galton-Watson process.

Everything the $q$ does is 'shifting' the probability distribution: You could define a prob distr. $p'_k=p_{k}\cdot q+p_{k-1}\cdot (1-q)$. I guess this is close to what you were thinking. Now just treat this process as a Galton-Watson process.
Using the Proposition 4 of the above link, the process dies with probability 1 as n goes to infinity iff $\mu' \leq 1$. (assuming some bound on the variance)

Comment: "strongly related to the Galton-Watson process" ?? This **IS** a Galton-Watson process.

Answer (score 0):

A branching process with i.i.d. offspring distributed as $p(x)$, will be extinted with probability one if $\mu <1 $ or $\mu=1$ with $\sigma^2>0$. (Grimett's book)

The problem here is that you don't know for sure if the individual will reproduce according to $p_x(x)$. From my understanding, the easier way would be to embed the death probability into $p_x(x)$. So, in that way, the expected value of the offspring of a certain individual is

$p_{x_0}(x) = qp_x(x)+(1-q)0 = qp_x(x)$

$E[X_o] = E[qp_x(x)] = q\mu$

So, if $q\mu \leq 1$, probability of extinction is one.